# Display a specific string in each frame with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm creating a video from a set of images like this

```
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -r 1 -i video_file.txt -crf 0 video_file.mkv
```

where video_file.txt contains the filepath of the images, which looks like this:

```
    file '/path/to/image1.tif'
    duration 0.5
    file_packet_metadata name=image1_name
    file '/path/to/image2.tif'
    duration 0.5
    file_packet_metadata name=image2_name
    ...
```

Concat reads all the lines starting with file '...' and correctly creates the output video.

I want that for each frame a specific string appears on screen, e.g. the filename or part of it.

I tried different options but none worked:

1. adding `-vf drawtext=textfile='path/to/frame.txt` to the ffmpeg command

   - where frame.txt contains in each line the text I want for each frame.
   - This fails because the entire text in the file is displayed over each frame.
2. adding `-vf drawtext=text=%{metadata\\:name}` to read the metadata name=image1_name in video_file.txt [source here](https://superuser.com/q/1336844/)

   - this simply displays the string 'name}' in the output
   - I tried {metadata\:name}, {metadata:name}, and {metadata:name}

How can I display a specific string for each frame ?

Comment: It's just an issue of escaping, provided your ffmpeg is recent enough. See https://superuser.com/q/1336844/

Comment: thank you @Gyan. That's indeed the source where I found the second solution I posted. But for some reason it doesn't work for me. I tried {metadata\\:name}, {metadata\:name}, and {metadata:name}. I updated my post.

Comment: I have ffmpeg version 4.1.3

Comment: Ok solved it. It was indeed a "issue of escaping". Because I concatenate the strings with python I need to escape the " when creating the command string. The right command has to be -vf "drawtext=text='%{metadata\:name}'" with the correct single and double quote marks as shown in https://superuser.com/q/1336844